# Rendering Thread of visual tree

Tags: wpf, multithreading, mvvm, rendering

I want to have possibility to abort the rendering thread, I have not found other solution to my problem :
I have a project with MVVM architecture ,in my ShellView I have a menu with buttons on which I can select different views in a ContentControl.
Due to many controls in each view and in order to improve the interaction with user, I collapse the visibility of the layout control which contains all child controls in the constructor of the view and next, render visible after the view is loaded.
It allows to first display the view before rendering child controls.

The problem is during the rendering, if I try to change the view I must wait for rendering of the current view before displaying of the new selected.

So my idea is to abort the rendering of the current view and display in priority the new view. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it’s your own code taking time in that child controls (i.e. if you’re rendering a 3D game using Direct3D interop, or generating some hard to compute bitmaps on the CPU, or use blocking I/O on the GUI thread, etc..) — in this case you could offload that work to some other thread (or switch to non-blocking I/O if that's the case), and only update the GUI thread once complete.

But if it’s WPF rendering that takes that much time, it means there’s something wrong with your visual tree. [Read this article for a start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.100).aspx). If you’re lucky you’ll only need to change a few lines of XAML to e.g. enable virtualization. If not, you’ll have to rework your whole GUI to fix the performance issues.